# SOQL add dummy column

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

Is it possible to create dummy column while fetching in SOQL
Like

```
select 'Dummy Column Text' as DUMMYCOL from MY_TABLE
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does this dummy column do??

Comment: I have to use this n commandline dataloader. Output file should be in that format

Answer (score 3):

No, You cannot. The Salesforce SOQL doesn't have this feature. You may create a field in the Object and you can retrieve it through query as it means like (Salesforce Object Query Language)